Is the condition $h(t)=0$ for $t<0$ necessary and sufficient for the causality of an LTI system?
My doubt is whether the conditions on the impulse response of an LTI systems on causality i.e., $h(t)=0$ for $t<0$ is bijective. I had this doubt in answering whether  the statement "An LTI system is causal if and only if its step response is zero for $t<0$" is true or not. I found contradicting answers on the internet, so I tried to reason as follows.
since $$s(t)=\int_{-\infty}^th(t)dt$$ I thought if the condition, $h(t)=0$ for $t<0$, is bijective with causality then this statement is correct.
By the way the question is from the textbook "signals and systems" by Alan oppenheim,
also any help on where to find a solution manual for the problems is much appreciated.

If an LTI system's impulse response is zero for $t<0$, there is no way for a response to be caused by future values of the input signal. This is easily seen from the convolution integral:
$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\Big |_{h(t)=0,t<0}=\int_{-\infty}^{t}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\tag{1}$$
where $y(t)$ is the system's response to the input $x(t)$, and $h(t)$ is the system's impulse response. Eq. $(1)$ shows that only past values of $x(t)$ up to the current time $t$ are used to compute the output $y(t)$.
On the other hand, if a system is causal, its impulse response must clearly be zero for $t<0$, otherwise it's straightforward to find an input signal (such as an impulse) which causes a non-causal response.
Consequently, the condition $h(t)=0$ for $t<0$ is necessary and sufficient for causality of an LTI system.
A very simple argument shows that the same is true for the step response.

Thank you for the clarification, could you point to some useful sources I am having trouble understanding these concepts

Nothing wrong with the answer, but just for notational clarity, would it be better for the upper bound in the second integral to be something like $t_{0}$? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're getting at?

@Guna: I think that working through Signals and Systems by Oppenheim will give you a good basic understanding of these things.

@Baddioes: The integration variable is $\tau$ and for a causal impulse response the upper integration limit is $t$, the same $t$ that is the argument of the response $y(t)$. Not sure if I understand what you mean ...

Ah, I see where I was confused and what you are getting at now. My bad!
